# Flutter-How to dismiss bottom modal sheet when onTap and Display snackbar?

Tags: flutter

I just want to implement the bottom modal sheet with a list of data( card ).when onTap the card the snack bar needs to be displayed. Before that bottom sheet will dismiss.

When I onTap bottom sheet by using `Navigate.pop(context)` it will dismiss. The snack bar will not be shown on the page.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please paste your code :)

Comment: Try this..  https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/returning-data/